# How to configure serenity report thread count?

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

By default Serenity report thread set to 80, during report generation it freezes the machine and I could not find anywhere to configure thread count , as can be seen from below written Test result report, Configured report threads:80, anyone knows how to change it?

```
Generating HTML Outcome Reports: false
[INFO] Generating test results for 70 tests
[INFO] 149 requirements loaded after 679 ms
[INFO] 149 related requirements found after 679 ms
[INFO] Generating test outcome reports: false
[INFO] Starting generating reports: 769 ms
```

### [INFO] Configured report threads: 80

```
[INFO] Finished generating test results for 70 tests after 8886 ms
GENERATE CUSTOM REPORTS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:32 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-13T00:24:30+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 52M/1305M
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the default value you are seeing:

> By default Serenity report thread set to 80 [...]

You are probably using a quad-core CPU with 8 virtual logical cores (SMT) because the default depends on the [number of processors that are available to the Java virtual machine](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/blob/master/serenity-core/src/main/java/net/thucydides/core/reports/NumberOfThreads.java).

Serenity uses that number to initialize the size of the thread pool it uses during report generation.

Here is how to change it:

1. Create a `serenity.properties` file
2. Set the number of threads via the `report.threads` property

The serenity.properties file is looked up in [multiple locations](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/blob/master/serenity-core/src/main/java/net/thucydides/core/util/PropertiesFileLocalPreferences.java). I recommend that create one for each of your test modules.